# Convert UTC date to current timezone

Tags: java, android, date

I have to convert a UTC date in this format "2016-09-25 17:26:12" to the current time zone of Android. I did this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(temp.getString("date"));
System.out.println(mydate.toString());
```

This works but I don't know why it print also "GMT+02:00". 
This is the Output: "Sun Sep 25 19:26:12 GMT+02:00 2016", I don't want to show "GMT+02:00".

**EDIT, CODE OF THE SOLUTION:**

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
SimpleDateFormat outputSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(temp.getString("date"));
System.out.println(outputSdf.format(myDate));
```

Comment: You haven't shown anything that prints anything out... if you're printing out `myDate.toString()`, that's just what `Date.toString()` does. Basically you should use another `SimpleDateFormat` with your desired output.

Comment: Yes, I'm printing myDate.toString()

Comment: So don't do that. Use SimlleDateFormat to format it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it print GMT+02 because this is your "local" timezone.
if you want to print the date without timezone information, use SimpleDateFormat to format the date to you liking.

edit : adding the code example (with your variable 'myDate')

```
SimpleDateFormat inputSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
inputSDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date myDate = inputSDF.parse("2016-09-25 17:26:12");
//
SimpleDateFormat outputSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(outputSDF.format(myDate));
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

yield on the (my) console (with my local timezone).

```
2016-09-25 19:26:12
Europe/Paris
```

Comment: Can you write the code please, I want the date to be in this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: doing this the output is in UTC timezone and not in mine, also if I do `outputSdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

Comment: creating a SimpleDateFormat instance without invoking the setTimeZone method implie that the SDF instance will have the same TimeZone as your JVM System. showing that when you printed the myDate.toString() and it ended in "GMT+02:00" i can assure that the instance you should have created will have your local timezone by default. **that is unless you're reusing the one you created with UTC to do the parsing**.

Comment: thanks, my mistake was that I reused the instance created with UTC

Comment: you're welcome, please note that the java Date object doesn't have a timezone "notion" so you should alvays use a SimpleDateFormat when you want to convert date 'point' to a timezoned human time representation (aka : formatted date :) )

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-09-25 17:26:12".replace( " " , "T" ) )
             .atZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.systemDefault() )
             .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ) )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## ISO 8601

You input string nearly complies with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format used by default with the java.time classes. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2016-09-25 17:26:12".replace( " " , "T" );
```

## `LocalDateTime`

The input lacks any indication of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). So we parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

You claim to know from the context of your app that this date-time value was intended to be [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). So we assign that offset as the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) to become a [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

You also say you want to adjust this value into the current default time zone of the user’s JVM (or Android runtime in this case). Know that this default can change at any time *during* your app’s execution. If the time zone is critical, you should explicitly ask the user for a desired/expected time zone. The `ZoneId` class represents a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault(); // Or, for example: ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z );
```

## Generate string

And you say you want to generate a string to represent this date-time value. You can specify any format you desire. But generally best to let java.time automatically localize for you according to the human language and cultural norms defined in a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) object. Use [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to specify length or abbreviation (`FULL`, `LONG`, [`MEDIUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#MEDIUM), `SHORT`).

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();  // Or, for example: Locale.CANADA_FRENCH
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: My Project currently use java7, and it doesn't have some of the classes you used, I will try it after when I move the project to java8, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @master94ga Re-read the second-to-last paragraph in my Answer, about [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: @BasilBourque (laugthing maniacally ...) thanks pal, you also suffered human idiocy named timezone hell and date format madness :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
system.out.println(myDate.getDay()+" "+myDate.getMonth()+" "+myDate.getYear());
```

Put what you need

Comment: This should work but I don't think is the best solution
Edit: also the method you say are deprecated in Android

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with set timezone method.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(rawQuestion.getString("AskDateTime"));
```

Comment: Is what I'm doing, the conversion work, but it add "GMT+02:00" to the output, I don't want it.

Comment: Try using TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()

Answer (score 0):

Below is the `toString()` implementation of `Date` class:

```
public String toString() {
        // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
        BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
        int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
        if (index == BaseCalendar.SUNDAY) {
            index = 8;
        }
        convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');                        // EEE
        convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[date.getMonth() - 1 + 2 + 7]).append(' ');  // MMM
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getDayOfMonth(), 2).append(' '); // dd

        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getHours(), 2).append(':');   // HH
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getMinutes(), 2).append(':'); // mm
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getSeconds(), 2).append(' '); // ss
        TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
        if (zi != null) {
            sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), TimeZone.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
        } else {
            sb.append("GMT");
        }
        sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

If you see, it appends Time zone info to the dates. If you don't want it to be printed, you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert `Date` to string, e.g.:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: Only doing myDate.toString() it applies the conversion in my timezone, with format it remains UTC