# How to convert UTC timestamp to asia/jakarta time

Tags: java, time

I have string timestamp like 
`2020-05-25 08:03:24`

I have tried to `split` the `String` using `" "` (a whitespace) as delimiter to get two `String`s `"2020-05-25"` and `"08:03:24"`. After that, I used `substring` to get the hours and added 7 to have jakarta time.
But when it is `17:01:00` for example, my calculated date is wrong.
The date given is in UTC.

I want to convert it become timezone [ASIA/Jakarta] how to convert utc timestamp become asia jakarta time?

Comment: Please, show your code

Comment: In addition to the good answer by deHaar below I recommend [this answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39692411/5772882).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `java.time` if you are using Java 8 or higher.

The library provides handy possibilities of converting datetimes that don't have information about a time zone (like your example `String`) to a zone and handle conversions from one zone to another.

See this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // datetime string without a time zone or offset
    String utcTimestamp = "2020-05-25 08:03:24";
    // parse the datetime as it is to an object that only knows date and time (no zone)
    LocalDateTime datetimeWithoutZone = LocalDateTime.parse(utcTimestamp,
                                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    // convert it to a zone-aware datetime object by adding a zone
    ZonedDateTime utcZdt = datetimeWithoutZone.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    // print the datetime in utc once
    System.out.println(utcZdt);
    // then convert the zoned datetime to a different time zone
    ZonedDateTime asiaJakartaZdt = utcZdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Jakarta"));
    // and print the result
    System.out.println(asiaJakartaZdt);
}
```

The output is

```
2020-05-25T08:03:24Z[UTC]
2020-05-25T15:03:24+07:00[Asia/Jakarta]
```

Comment: Oh thanks for that example

Comment: @yuyukungkung You're welcome...